# Expected value $E(e^{X_t})$ when $(X_t)$ is a Markov process with transition matrix $P$

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains

I have a variable, X, that follows a Markov process with a transition matrix that is not symmetric. I want to compute the expected value of the exponential of that variable at horizon T.

I have seen closed form solutions for computing the expectation of X. But I am not sure how to translate that when I am taking the exponential of X.

Is there a standard reference?

Comment: thanks @glorfindel for editing the statement to making it easier to read

Comment: For a Markov process on some state space $S$, with initial distribution $\nu$ and transition kernel $(p_t)$, $$E(e^{X_t})=\iint_{S\times S}e^xp_t(z,dx)\nu(dz)$$

Comment: FYI, the phrase "a variable, X, that follows a Markov process" is meaningless.